# One Navi revealing themselves to another Navi

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, nevua-prophecy, yosef, parashat-vayeishev, miketz

Rav Moshe Feinstein is quoted in Kol Ram asking why didn't Yosef reveal to his father that he is alive in Egypt. He answers that maybe one navi cannot reveal themselves to another navi without HaShem allowing it and that is why Yitzchak also didn't tell Yaakov even though he knew (Rashi 37:33).

Is there such a concept or this is Rav Moshe's chiddush?

Comment: I don't even know what that means ("one navi cannot reveal themselves to another without Hashem allowing it"). _Elisha_ revealed himself to the _Shunamis_. _Moshe_ revealed himself to _Yisro_ (though I guess that's before he was a _navi_). _Yosef_ revealed himself to the minister of bakers.

Comment: @msh210 Perhaps he means "to another [navi]"?

Comment: It probably means not to reveal his Nevua, though I don't get how this applies to Yosef. It does fit for Yitzchok.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe so. But _Aharon_ revealed himself to _Moshe_. And _Yaakov_ to _Yitzchak_. And, and, and.

Comment: Can you provide a source so we can see the original?

Comment: I meant one Navi to another navi,thought that was clear

Comment: I can take a pic of the source later

Comment: Is this from volume one, two, or three? Or the new printing?

Comment: The new one........

Comment: Hhmm. I have three old three. Didn't buy the new one. From the way you worded it, it sounds like he's admitting to  saying a chidush.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that Rav Moshe didn't get it from this source, but:
R. Nissim (also known as the Ran) writes in his commentary to the Torah (see http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?7943&lang=eng page 366 on the website, ער in the sefer) that before there were famous well-recognized prophets, early prophets were not allowed to reveal their prophecies to others unless explicitly told to do so. In his case, R. Nissim writes that Abraham was not allowed to tell his wife Sarah his prophecy that she would give birth to a son (which is why the angels came to inform of this even though God already told it to Abraham). In that case, Abraham was not allowed to reveal the information to his wife even though she was a prophetess in her own right.

Comment: Why do you think k he didn't get it from the Ran?